# How do I filter date on front end which are appears from mysql database?

Tags: angularjs, mysql-workbench

I have tried a lot to display date in corrected format on front end from database.

In mysql database the column has it's datatype as date only then what should i do to display it correctly.
Here is the code i tried

```
<section class="tab-section tab-arrow review-tab-list">
            <ul ng-if= "underReviewLoanDetails.length > 0">
                <li ng-repeat='underReviewLoanDetails in underReviewLoanDetails | filter:searchText'  ng-click="underReviewLoanPage(underReviewLoanDetails)">
                <a class="tab review-tab">
                    <div class="tabuser-img"><img src="{{underReviewLoanDetails.UserImage}}"></div>
                    <div class="tab-text">
                        <div class="tab-middletext">
                            <h2>{{underReviewLoanDetails.UserName}</h2> 
                            <p>{{"Submitted " + underReviewLoanDetails.RequestedDate  }}</p>
                        </div>
                        <label>{{underReviewLoanDetails.ProjectTitle}}</label>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

Here underReviewLoanDetails is a JSON from database

Comment: I have an urgent requirement of this give replies as soon as possible

Comment: Please read this carefully before asking such questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You may consider to update your question.

Comment: one update I have also tried this code {{"Submitted " + underReviewLoanDetails.RequestedDate | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}}

Comment: Please try to give an answer atleast

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the "Submitted" out of the interpolation:

> "Submitted "{{underReviewLoanDetails.RequestedDate|date:"dd-MM-yyy"}}

If this String is inside the Interpolation the filter tries to filter "Submitted 2018-02-28"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  <p>{{"Submitted " + underReviewLoanDetails.RequestedDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</p>
```